# how to scrape containt of class in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to append href from this class:

```
<a class="_2UzuFa" href="/awg-all-weather-gear-solid-men-polo-neck-black-grey-t-shirt/p/itm19ae710c69708?pid=TSHGFKPZNGYMP2FC&amp;lid=LSTTSHGFKPZNGYMP2FCZPKPX3&amp;marketplace=FLIPKART&amp;store=clo%2Fash%2Fank%2Fedy&amp;srno=b_1_38&amp;otracker=browse&amp;fm=organic&amp;iid=en_7%2Fz2ZgorbMeTmb%2F05oING%2BjZoEV8lwngUWQpEDanwo443TzRZ2XfvI9qIOekIcXbWiZZReg3l4w%2Fa03968TVxw%3D%3D&amp;ppt=None&amp;ppn=None&amp;ssid=3o5k6hnkq80000001660826655971"J5 -o7Q4n"></a>
```

my code =

```
for item in class:
   containt = soup.find('href)
   print(containt)
```

its not working

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. "not working" is not a helpful problem description. I don't see any code trying to append anything. Totally unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use reserved keywords like `class` as variable name and to extract the `href`s value from a `tag` use `.get('href')`.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<a class="_2UzuFa" href="/awg-all-weather-gear-solid-men-polo-neck-black-grey-t-shirt/p/itm19ae710c69708?pid=TSHGFKPZNGYMP2FC&amp;lid=LSTTSHGFKPZNGYMP2FCZPKPX3&amp;marketplace=FLIPKART&amp;store=clo%2Fash%2Fank%2Fedy&amp;srno=b_1_38&amp;otracker=browse&amp;fm=organic&amp;iid=en_7%2Fz2ZgorbMeTmb%2F05oING%2BjZoEV8lwngUWQpEDanwo443TzRZ2XfvI9qIOekIcXbWiZZReg3l4w%2Fa03968TVxw%3D%3D&amp;ppt=None&amp;ppn=None&amp;ssid=3o5k6hnkq80000001660826655971"J5 -o7Q4n"></a>'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.select('a'):
    print(a.get('href'))
```

##### Output

```
/awg-all-weather-gear-solid-men-polo-neck-black-grey-t-shirt/p/itm19ae710c69708?pid=TSHGFKPZNGYMP2FC&lid=LSTTSHGFKPZNGYMP2FCZPKPX3&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=clo%2Fash%2Fank%2Fedy&srno=b_1_38&otracker=browse&fm=organic&iid=en_7%2Fz2ZgorbMeTmb%2F05oING%2BjZoEV8lwngUWQpEDanwo443TzRZ2XfvI9qIOekIcXbWiZZReg3l4w%2Fa03968TVxw%3D%3D&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=3o5k6hnkq80000001660826655971
```

##### Example based on flipkart

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://www.flipkart.com/mens-tshirts/awg-all-weather-gear~brand/pr?sid=clo,ash,ank,edy&marketplace=FLIPKART&otracker=product_breadCrumbs_AWG+All+Weather+Gear+Men%27s+T-shirts'
soup =BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

for e in soup.select('a._2UzuFa'):
    print('https://www.flipkart.com'+e.get('href'))
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, this is the actually i want...

Comment: sir i need one more help, can you please help me in this